# Exporting bookmarks from Opera to Chrome while preserving folder structure

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, opera, export

I'm trying to export my bookmarks from Opera 45.0.2552.888 to Chrome 58.0.3029.110. [This](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/bookmarks-import-export/?display=en) utility does manage to export the bookmarks, but when imported to Chrome, only folders with bookmarks in them are preserved (i.e. their parent folders are not).

Opera does not seem to have the option to export bookmarks to an HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a solution - a rather unwieldy one, but a solution nonetheless. What one can do is to copy Opera's bookmarks file, located at

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable
```

to

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

It is then possible to export the bookmarks to a HTML file using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Marcel, Actually I found a solution.

Step 1: Go to Bookmarks Menu from Opera and then go for export bookmarks.

[image]

Step 2: Save bookmark file with HTML extension.

[image]

Step 3: Go to Chrome and open import bookmarks and settings. Then Choose Bookmarks HTML File.

Step 4: Then choose the Bookmarks HTML file you saved and then open.

This is solution for latest Opera and Chrome version. I hope this works for you too.